# Flutter, handling keyboard key events, limit action just to keyDown

Tags: flutter, keyboard-events

In Flutter, I'm looking to use keyboard events, issue is that when I press arrow down key, action happens both on keyDown and keyUp event, in code example code will print word down two times, on key press and upon releasing the key, I want it to print it just on keyDown event instead and to ignore keyUp, as to have it print in console down just once after pressing key down and releasing it

thank you

```
   import 'package:flutter/services.dart';  //<-- needed for the keypress comparisons

FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();  // <-- still no idea what this is.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode); // <-- yup.  magic. no idea.
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: RawKeyboardListener(
          autofocus: true,
          focusNode: focusNode,   // <-- more magic
          onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
            if (event.data.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowDown) {
               print(down);
               }
          },
          child: GridView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: 300,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 30),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    color: Colors.grey,         
              },
            ),
          ),
      );
  }
```

Comment: your `event` can be `RawKeyDownEvent` or `RawKeyUpEvent` so you can add some `if` for selecting particular event type

Comment: Thank you, how ever I don't know how to implement this in my code, from documentation, it seems I should create RawKeyDownEvent class?

Could you please show me how can I implement RawKeyDownEvent into code in the question?

Comment: `if (event is RawKeyDownEvent) print('down');`

Comment: Thank you very much, issue solved, if you want, write it as an answer and i'l accept it as correct

Comment: your welcome, write a self answer then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Android TV with remote control

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawKeyboardListener(
        autofocus: true,
        focusNode: FocusNode(),
        onKey:(event){
            // print(event);
            if(event is RawKeyDownEvent){ // just keyDown
                print(event.logicalKey.keyLabel); // Arrow Down || Arrow Up || Arrow Left || Arrow Right || Select || Go Back               
            }
        },
        child:Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text('Flutter test keys'),
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2023 I ended up using what Cesar Devasa said, but instead with

`if (event is KeyDownEvent)`

The official docs further explain the update.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/KeyDownEvent-class.html